# Python: adding two items from a list as key:pair to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

Trying to convert a list of items as key:value pairs to a dict:

```
def make_dict(a_list, category_name):

    a_dict = {}


    for i in range(0, len(a_list), 2):
        a_dict[a_list[i]] = a_list[i+1]
    return a_dict
```

getting this error:

```
a_dict[a_list[i]] = a_list[i+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand why but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any solutions?

Also, it is collecting the key:value pairs right before it goes out of range.

Comment: Can you please add sample input and expected output?

Comment: Your code should work, but only if there are an even number of items in `a_list`. Please make sure that is the case.

Comment: You can also do `dict(zip(a_list[::2], a_list[1::2]))`.

Comment: @jdehesa very easy solution, just wondering could you explain the semi colons `(a_list[::2], a_list[1::2])`  so I can do my own further research to fully understanding what's going on there? Cheers.

Comment: @JoshQuinn Yes, list slicing syntax is `my_list[first:last:step]`, `first` defaults to the start of the list, `last` to the end and `step` to 1. Gives you a new list from `first` to `last` (not included) taking 1 in `step` items. There are more tricks (you can have step <0 to go backwards, where `first` and `last` defaults are reversed, or use indices <0 for positions from the end so `my_list[-2:]` takes the last 2 items). I take even and odd items and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to make a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: Ok thank you. Perhaps you could assist on a new question I have just raised?

Answer (score 1):

You code should work for even number of elements in a list, but when you have odd number of elements the element at index `i+1` does not exist, hence the error.

You can also `zip` over the same iterator to consume successive values as pairs, with dict comprehension:

```
In [239]: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]                                                                                                                                                                          

In [240]: {k: v for k, v in zip(*[iter(l)] * 2)}                                                                                                                                                            
Out[240]: {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

For an odd number of elements, you can use `itertools.zip_longest` with a `fillvalue` to fill in missing last value:

```
In [241]: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                                                                                                                                                                       

In [242]: {k: v for k, v in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(l)] * 2, fillvalue=None)}                                                                                                                          
Out[242]: {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: None}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is currently ending at the length of the list (`len(a_list)`), but calling the index at that length value will break it. Just fix your loop to stop one early:

```
    for i in range(0, len(a_list)-1, 2): #subtract 1 from length!
        a_dict[a_list[i]] = a_list[i+1]
```